# Recursive function to compiled version

Tags: compile

I have looked up some articles about the compiling recursive functions. I know usually there is no general solution to these kinds of questions. And my case is a little bit different (or more complicated) so I decide to simplify it and ask here:

The original recursive function in my case has been simplified as below:

```
Clear[f]
x = 0.1; f[0] = 1.; f[1] = 2.;
f[n_] := f[n] = 20*x*f[n - 1] + n*f[n - 2];
```

And my desired output result was calculated by:

```
Table[f[n] 2 n x, {n, 0, 10}]
(* Output: {0., 0.4, 2.4, 10.8, 48., 210., 936., 4242., 19680., 93366., 453480.} *)
```

To transform it into a compiled version, what I did is that I first wrote a compiled `fc` function as shown below:  (Note: it's not the best way to use `Do` but that's all I can think of ):

```
fc = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Module[{t}, t = {1., 2};
   t = Join[t, Table[0., {10}]];
   Do[t[[n + 2]] = (20*x*t[[n + 1]] + (n + 1)*t[[n]]), {n, 10}]; Most@t]
  ]
```

It works okay for using `fc` as a compiled replacement by `f`:

```
Table[f[n], {n, 0, 10}]
(*{1, 2, 6., 18., 60., 210., 780., 3030., 12300., 51870., 226740.}*)

fc[0.1] 
(*{1., 2., 6., 18., 60., 210., 780., 3030., 12300., 51870.,226740.}*)
```

However, my questions are:

1- I don't know how to take the `2*n*x` part into the final computation to get my desired result.

2- `fc` only works fine when `x` is one-dimensional value. But my project requires larger data-set to handle with and that's why I am trying to use `Compile`. So how to adjust it to work on a real number list, for example, when `x = {0.1,0.2,0.3...}`?

Comment: What do you mean by " I don't know how to take the 2*n*x part into the final computation to get my desired result." What _is_ your desired result?

Comment: My final computation would include `2*n*x`, so in the uncompiled version, it was calculated by `Table[f[n] 2*n*x, {n, 0, 10}]`, I do not know how to transform this.

Comment: Okay. I edited my post. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how to adjust it to work on a real number list, for example, when `x = {0.1,0.2,0.3...}`?

If `x` is a list of reals, then just compile `fc` with the addictional option `RuntimeAttributes-> {Listable}` and call `fc[x]`. `Parallelization -> True` will also enable parallelization (does only work if `RuntimeAttributes-> {Listable}` is also set).

```
fc2 = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {iter, _Integer}},
   Module[{t},
    t = {1., 2.};
    t = Join[t, Table[0., {iter}]];
    Do[
     t[[n + 2]] = (20. x t[[n + 1]] + (n + 1) t[[n]]),
     {n, iter}
     ];
    Most[t] Range[0, iter] (2. x)
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

A quick test (also with the vectorized version of your old memoization approach):

```
x = Subdivide[0., 10., 1000000];
ClearAll[f];
f[0] = 1. + 0. x; f[1] = 2. + 0. x;
f[n_] := f[n] = 20. x f[n - 1] + n f[n - 2];
aa = Transpose[Table[f[n] 2 n x, {n, 0, 50}]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
bb = fc2[x, 50]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
aa == bb
```

> 1.59957
>
> 0.352834
>
> True